# Chartjs: how to show only max and min values on y-axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

Using Chart.js, I'd like to display only two labels (or ticks) on the y-axis: the max and min of the values. The values are all floating point numbers.

I'm not sure if the callback function `yAxis.ticks.callback` is the place to do it.

Comment: how can we do the same in x axis?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following callback function for y-axis ticks to achieve that :

```
callback: function(value, index, values) {
   if (index === values.length - 1) return Math.min.apply(this, dataArr);
   else if (index === 0) return Math.max.apply(this, dataArr);
   else return '';
}
```

**note:** you must use a separate array for data values *(here it's `dataArr`)*, instead of an in-line one.

**EDIT :**

add the following in your y-axis ticks config to make the data-points perfectly aligned with the ticks :

```
min: Math.min.apply(this, dataArr),
max: Math.max.apply(this, dataArr)
```

---

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ**

```js
var dataArr = [154.23, 203.21, 429.01, 637.41];
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'LINE',
         data: dataArr,
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)',
         fill: false,
         tension: 0
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               min: Math.min.apply(this, dataArr),
               max: Math.max.apply(this, dataArr),
               callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  if (index === values.length - 1) return Math.min.apply(this, dataArr);
                  else if (index === 0) return Math.max.apply(this, dataArr);
                  else return '';
               }
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not quite what I am looking for. The data in my problem are floating point numbers, and I want the y-axis to display only the max and min of the data set. For example, the values might be `[154.23, 203.21, 429.01, 637.41]`. I want to show on the y-axis only the max and min values: `154.23` and `637.41` The nice number algorithm rounds these values, which is not what I want.

Comment: That is closer, but the problem with this solution is that the values on the y-axis don't necessarily align with the values in the chart.  You are replacing the highest 'nice number' with the actual max, and the lowest 'nice number' with the actual min.  The max and min are not being placed exactly where they should fall on the y-axis. This is why I don't think the solution can be attained by using the callback alone.

Comment: then add `min: Math.min.apply(this, dataArr)` and `max: Math.max.apply(this, dataArr)` to the y-axis ticks.

Comment: Yes! I think that works. https://jsfiddle.net/tbarmann/j1mxowoz/1/ Now how would I add padding on the top and bottom so that the values don't extend to the full top and bottom?

Comment: you can decrease/increase min/max value by some number respectively - https://jsfiddle.net/j1mxowoz/3/, but then again the data-points won't be aligned and there's no other way to do so.. what you currently have is the correct behavior...

Comment: perhaps you can do this - https://jsfiddle.net/j1mxowoz/6/ at the most..

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, ℊααnd !

Comment: how can we do the same in x axis?

Comment: because min/max logic is repeated it should be extracted to a variable. This yields a simpler callback as: `callback: value => (value === maxScore || value === minScore ? value : '')`